# What happpens inside of the for loop here?

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_vectors(list_v, list_label, list_color):
    _, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-10, 10))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-10, 10))


plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
for i, v in enumerate(list_v):
    sgn = 0.4 * np.array([[1] if i==0 else [i] for i in np.sign(v)])
    plt.quiver(v[0], v[1], color=list_color[i], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
    ax.text(v[0]-0.2+sgn[0], v[1]-0.2+sgn[1], list_label[i], fontsize=14, color=list_color[i])

plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()

v = np.array([[1],[3]])
# Arguments: list of vectors as NumPy arrays, labels, colors.
plot_vectors([v], [f"$v$"], ["black"])
```

I am trying to understand this code, and I have a misunderstanding about the inside of the for loop. I mean, what happens there?
By the way, it plots a vector in the coordinate system.

Comment: See [plt.quiver](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) and [quiver demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_simple_demo.html) to get an idea about matplotlib's `quiver` function.

Comment: It looks like you've destroyed the original indentation of the code.  To add a code block, you can put a line with triple backticks (```) before and after the code. It is not sure where you copied the code from, but `enumerate` should be avoided whenever possible, especially when the code reuses the same variable name for another purpose. A "pythonic" for loop would look like `for v, color, label in zip(list_v, list_color, list_label):`.  Further, mixing the `plt` and the `ax` interface makes for badly readable code. `np.sign` is used very weirdly to calculate an offset.